# Get MIME type of a file without extension in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mime-types

Given I have a file without extension appended to its name, ex: `images/cat_photo`

Is there a method in Node.js to extract MIME type of a given file? Module [*mime*](https://github.com/broofa/node-mime) in this case does not work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there is a module called [mmmagic](https://github.com/mscdex/mmmagic). It tries best to guess the MIME of a file by analysing its content.

The code will look like this (taken from [example](https://github.com/mscdex/mmmagic)):

```
var mmm = require('mmmagic'),
var magic = new mmm.Magic(mmm.MAGIC_MIME_TYPE);

magic.detectFile('node_modules/mmmagic/build/Release/magic.node', function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
});
```

But keep in mind, that the guessing of a MIME type may not always lead to right answer.

Feel free to read up on types signatures on a [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures).

Comment: He doesn't need to download a package to do this, he can do this with vanilla JS

Comment: @gbrennon Prove this by posting an answer which shows this. Your comment is not useful otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility is to use exec or execSync function to run the 'file' command on Linux SO:

```
/**
 * Get the file mime type from path. No extension required.
 * @param filePath Path to the file
 */
function getMimeFromPath(filePath) {
    const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;
    const mimeType = execSync('file --mime-type -b "' + filePath + '"').toString();
    return mimeType.trim();
}
```

However is not the best solution since only works in Linux. For running this in Windows check this Superuser question:
https://superuser.com/questions/272338/what-is-the-equivalent-to-the-linux-file-command-for-windows

Greetings.

Answer (score -8):

You could simply use [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and then take the last element of the array which will be the type.

You can take the last element on the array using the pop method:

```js
const mimeType = fileName.split('.').pop()
```

or

```js
const type = mimeType.split('/')
```

then `type[1]` will have the extension

Comment: The OP stated that the file **doesn't have** extension. Additionally, the file extension is **not** a MIME type...

Comment: Then alandarev answer will be the best choice, but im not sure that its best practice to accept files which unknown